# Is the set $\Omega=\{z\in\mathbb{C} : |Re(f(z)|\leq|Im(f(z))|\}$ closed in $\mathbb{C}$

Tags: complex-analysis

Suppoe $f$ is an entire function, I want to know if this set $\Omega=\{z\in\mathbb{C} : |Re(f(z)|\leq|Im(f(z))|\}$ is closed?
I know that usually we show its complement is open, but I don't have a picture in my mind for this set. How do we show that we can put an open ball in its complement for every point $z$ in $\Omega$.

Comment: $f(\Bbb{C})\setminus\Omega=\{z\in\mathbb{C} : |\Re(f(z)|\gt|\Im(f(z))|\}$

Comment: It will be easy to show that any convergent sequence in $\Omega$ has its limit in $\Omega.$

Comment: This is a very good idea! Thank you!!!

Comment: Every function in the list $$f\qquad\Re\qquad\Im\qquad|\cdot|$$ is continuous hence...